# Google app script - how to count number of google form response

Tags: google-apps-script

It is my first time writing google app script and I am desperately need help.

The purpose is to set up a workshop sign up form. Based on how many people already signed up, an email is sent out to inform if sign up was successful, or was put in the wait list.

I copied code from a [tutorial](http://alamoxie.com/blog/tech-tips/sending-confirmation-emails-google-docs-form/). But need help to get the count of form responses. Here is how it looks like now:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var timestamp = e.values[0];
  var yourName = e.values[1];
  var toAddress = e.values[2];

  var subject = "Workshop Confirmation";
  var emailBody = "Thank you for your submitted on " + timestamp 

  var num_response = COUNT_NUMBER_OF_RESPONSE // <-- need help here
  var LIMIT = 15
  if (num_response <= LIMIT) {
    emailBody = emailBody + "\n\nYou are enrolled in the workshop";
  }
  else {
    var wait = num_response - LIMIT
    emailBody = emailBody + "\n\nThe workshop is full. You are #" + wait + " in the waiting list"
  }

  emailBody = emailBody + "\n\nThe details you entered were as follows: " +
      "\nYour Name: " + yourName +
      "\nYour Email: " + toAddress ;
  MailApp.sendEmail(toAddress, subject,
                   emailBody, optAdvancedArgs);
}
```

I have no clue how to find right answer in the google app document. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see in the tutorial, this script is embedded in a spreadsheet so the easiest would be to count the number of rows and substract 1 because of the headers...

There is a method for that : [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet?hl=en#getLastRow%28%29), the doc refered in this link should give you enough information to write the few lines of code you need...

test :

```
function xx(){
  var lr = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getLastRow()-1;
  Logger.log(lr);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

How about the composite function

```
FormApp.getActiveForm().getResponses().length
```

no need to go around looking for the spreadsheet (since in my experience, the *spreadsheet* is not always up to date, whereas the *form* is)

Answer (score 0):

Script on form (not spreadsheet)

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
 var num_response = FormApp.getActiveForm().getResponses().length
 var LIMIT = 20 //or whatever
 if (num_response < LIMIT) {
  }
 else {
 var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
 form.setAcceptingResponses(false);
  }
 }
```